# Default select value in form from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

How could I make the following select field default to the currently selected rid?

```
<form method="GET" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<select name='rid'>
<?php
    $query= "SELECT * FROM resources ORDER BY resname";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
    {
        $rid = $row['rid'];
        echo "<option value='".$rid."'>"
        .$row['resname']
        ."</option>\n";
    }
?>
</select>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

The codes pretty ugly, don't lynch me.

Comment: `The codes pretty ugly, don't lynch me.` Then why not fix it?

Comment: @Daan I'll do so now, it was quickly thrown together for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you look into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MYSQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) because `mysql_` is depreciated as of PHP 5.5.0.

Anyways, we can do it quickly with a [ternary operator](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/3/12/4)

```
echo "<option value='".$rid."' ".((isset($_GET['rid']) && $_GET['rid'] == $rid) ? 'SELECTED' : '').">"
```

Comment: I updated this because I noticed that you're using the `GET` method and not `POST`

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM resources ORDER BY resname";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['rid'] . "'"; 
if (isset($_POST['rid']) && $_POST['rid'] == $row['rid']) {
    echo ' selected="selected"';
}
echo ">" . $row['resname'] . "</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM resources ORDER BY resname";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['rid'] . "'"; 
    if (isset($_GET['rid']) && $_GET['rid'] == $row['rid']) {
        echo ' selected="selected"';
    }
    echo ">" . $row['resname'] . "</option>\n";
}
```

Comment: It would make more sense to use a ternary operator for this, it's such a little thing and could be combined to have only one variable.